# Orchard CMS and Shibboleth authentication

Tags: orchardcms, shibboleth

We're looking at using Orchard for an internal site.

We currently use [Shibboleth](http://shibboleth.net/) for initial authentication, which makes a POST back to our site in the format of `http://domain/Shibboleth.sso/{stuff}`

In our current ASP.NET MVC website we needed to just modify the Global.asax with the following:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Shibboleth.sso/{isapiInfo}/{isapiDetails}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Shibboleth.sso/{*pathInfo}");
```

Unfortunately, Orchard doesn't allow us to go that route, so after some research it looks like it requires a handler to be added.

Via IIS (Server 2008 R2) this was added into the web.config within the handlers group:

```
<add name="Shib" path="*.sso" verb="*" modules="IsapiFilterModule" scriptProcessor="C:\{path}\isapi_shib.dll" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

I've tried a couple different variations of this, and still no dice.

Since I pulled down the source anyway, I tried going the simple route of just adding the two `routes.IgnoreRoute` calls and re-building, but that results in the same issue.

If I remove the Shib requirement then Orchard starts fine, and if I put in a new MVC project with Shib on (and our two IgnoreRoute calls added) that also works fine.

The browser is returning a 404 (blank page), so I have the feeling that Orchard is still grabbing the request.

Any suggestions on how I could go about getting Orchard to skip over this path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing two things.

First, I created a new module using Not Found MVC as a template. In particular [the InstallerModule code](https://github.com/andrewdavey/NotFoundMvc/blob/master/src/NotFoundMvc/InstallerModule.cs).

I added the following in system.web > httpModules:

```
<add name="InstallerModule" type="IgnoreShibboleth.InstallerModule, IgnoreShibboleth" />
```

I also added the same to system.webServer > modules.

All the code did was add in the ignore routes.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("Shibboleth.sso/{isapiInfo}/{isapiDetails}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("Shibboleth.sso/{*pathInfo}");
```

The final step I was really close on. I added the following under system.webServer > handlers, immediately after the `<clear />`:

```
<add name="Shib" path="*.sso" verb="*" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="{path-to}\lib\shibboleth\isapi_shib.dll" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" preCondition="integratedMode,bitness64" />
```

The last time wasn't required in the past, but seems necessary for something Orchard is doing.